# wpf / net framework 4.0 / charts and diagrams

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0

I would like to draw diagrams and charts and have the following restrictions:  
- net framework 4.0  
- wpf (not windows forms if possible)  
- running as windows application (not as a web application)  
- c# with visual studio 2010 express

What I know:

- the WPF toolkit is not running with net 4.0 (I have tried it already)

- there is an assembly System.Web.DataVisualization - but I can't use it because it is for .aspx application (for the web)

Has anyone any idea how I can solve this? I would like to avoid using an external tool but if there is no other option I would do that.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using WPF toolkit in a WPF application with .Net 4.0 and i works just fine.

I used this tutorial to draw my chart:
http://www.itdevspace.com/2010/09/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-chart-example.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a free framework called [oxyplot](http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/).
[Here](http://www.oxyplot.org/ExampleBrowser/) are examples of its capabilities (uses Silverlight but this is available for WPF too)
At the moment this project is admittedly quite poorly documented, I work out how to use it mainly through the provided examples. However I enjoy using it and sound promising for the future.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [LightningChart](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-ultimate-sdk/) as well!
We have a wide range of charts available, they're fast, smooth, and very easy to set up and use. There are also bindable (if you prefer the MVVM pattern) or non-bindable flavors for you to pick from, with tons of customization options. Have a look at our [gallery](https://www.arction.com/gallery/) to see if anything fits your use case!

I'm a dev at LightningChart, so if you are stuck with anything, feel free to message me! :)